# get future time value

Tags: c++

```
#include <time.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    time_t current = time(0);

    cout << ctime(&current) << endl; 
    return 0;
}
```

How can I get the future time, say 1 hour later, from the current time?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[time(2)](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/time.html) returns the number of seconds since 1970-01-01 00:00:00 +0000 (UTC). One hour later would be `current + 3600`.

```
time_t current   = time(0);
time_t inOneHour = current + (60*60); // 60 minutes of 60 sec.

cout << "Now: " << ctime(&current) << "\n" 
     << "In 1 hour: " << ctime(&inOneHour)
     << "\n";
```

Comment: Note that [`time()` is not guaranteed to return time as a number of seconds after an epoch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_t) by the C standard, although the behavior is guaranteed by POSIX.

Comment: @silico: Do you have a reference? I though that was the definition of time(2) as shown in the link provided above.

Comment: @Martin York: Note that the page at the link provided says at the bottom "Conforming to SVr4, 4.3BSD, POSIX". The ISO C standard itself doesn't actually say anything about the encoding of `time_t`.

Comment: @In silico: So all POSIX compliant systems return the seconds from the epoch. And since time() is a POSIX defined function this is always true !

Comment: @Martin York: Yes. The OP should check the documentation for their specific platform if POSIX compliance with respect to `time()` is not certain.

Comment: So I can just use cout << current + 3600;  ?  This gave me an integer value 1291856041.

Comment: This will show you the seconds ;) not the ctime() formatted representation. But yes, you can :)

Comment: @FAS: `current += 3600; cout << ctime(&current) << endl; `

Comment: @Martin, thank you for that nice edit, still learning how to best answer :)